# Nodejs stream memory leak

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, stream

I have write/read streams in nodejs. There is a lot of data constantly going through them, especially through read Stream. Program memory usage grows quickly and after like 200MB data transferred through read Stream the program gets "killed" by the OS.

There is another program that writes into read Stream.
How can I stop memory growth?

```js
var fs = require('fs');

var writableStream = fs.createWriteStream('outStream');
var readableStream = fs.createReadStream('inStream');

readableStream.setEncoding('ascii');

var totalReceivedLength=0;

readableStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
totalReceivedLength+=chunk.length;
});

readableStream.on('end', function() {
 readableStream.destroy();
 console.log(data.length);
});
```

I use

```
top | grep nodejs
```

to monitor memory usage.

Comment: Is your code complete? I see "console.log(data.length);"

Where is "data" variable define and used?

Comment: My mistake. The code is only a small piece of bigger code, which includes "data" variable.

Comment: Please include how you create the `data` variable - are you accumulating your data from the chunks of the stream?